# Temp Channels Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a simple discord bot with a couple of commands/events in it.
Now, I wanted to create temp channels, like when I join a specific voice channel, it will create another one which is called **"{member.name}'s Channel"**. 
I watched tutorials, and read many stackoverflow posts, of people who had a similar or the same idea, but they were smarter than I am XD.
So, can someone send a good link to a tutorial (where it is explained from start to end) or just write some very simple code u know?
My biggest problem is that I dont know how to check if a user joined a specific voice channel.
Sorry I know that this is not the right way of using Stack Overflow, but I had no idea what to do

Answer (score 1):

This is really quite simple.

First thing you want to do is detect when a users joins the voice channel:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        if after.channel.id == [YOUR_CHANNEL_ID]:
            #do stuff here
```

Then to create a channel for that user you simply do this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        if after.channel.id == [YOUR_CHANNEL_ID]:
            await after.channel.guild.create_text_channel(f'{member.name}'s channel!')
```

PS: Welcome to stack overflow, its hard to get any support on a question when your just starting. people will say stuff like "read this rule on this page" just weird stuff. Try to stick to the rules and make your questions to the best you can. Have a great day!

Comment: Thank you for answering :), for some reason he doesnt detects when i join the voice channel, i replaced the [YOUR_CHANNEL_ID] with the right channel id, but still nothing is happening...
I also changed: ´await after.channel.guild.create_text_channel(f'{member.name}'s channel!')´
because there were not enoug '

Comment: have you enabled the members intent for your bot?

Comment: uhmmm no? i litterally dont even know what it is... ._. is it like, something has to be true or imported?

Comment: ok, please add me on discord: `LUNA (i love sam)#0446` and ill help you to enable it and fix the code/

Comment: i mean, unfortunately im not able to speak to u in a voice chat, (sorry for that)

Comment: but i am Yami.Anime on Discord.